# Looking for lightweight modal popup JS library that runs stand alone

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

I need a pointer to a library to show modal dialog popup with HTML content. The library should be able to work in random websites without relaying on a library like jquery etc..

My requirements:
1. beautiful design (shadow is a plus for example).
2. compatibility with arbitrary doctypes
3. lightweight and quick to load.

thanks

Comment: Any particular reason you want to avoid a library (such as jQuery)? They help a _ton_ with cross-browser compatibility issues.

Comment: Its for a sas service which is hooked into random sites. I dont want to load jquery for the popup alone.

Comment: If you load jQuery from http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js the chances are the user will have downloaded it already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non jquery reliance will really limit the options nowadays - but [simplemodal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/) is pretty nice if you rethink your jquery reliance requirement

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar need and put together the following modal library:

https://github.com/Nycto/PicoModal